# Bad Request when registering with passport

Tags: express, authentication, mongoose, passport.js, mean-stack

I am trying to build an authentication panel for the MEAN stack using PassportJS. I have the following code for registering new users with **email**(instead of the default username) and password:

```
router.post("/register", function (req, res) {
  var newUser = new User({
    username: req.body.email
  });
  User.register(newUser, req.body.password, function (err, user) {
    if (err) {
      return res.render('account/signup');
    }
    passport.authenticate("local")(req, res, function () {
      res.redirect("/account/profile");
    });
  });
});
```

However, when running the server, I am presented with a screen on which it is written *Bad Request*.
It can be assumed that the new user account is being successfully created as I am able to log in that account.

I believe that the error originates somewhere around here:

```
passport.authenticate("local")(req, res, function () {
  res.redirect("/account/profile");
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`passport.authenticate` is a middleware, which means that you have to call it with 3 parameters `(req, res, next)`:

```
...
passport.authenticate("local", function(err, user, info) {

    if (err) return next(err); 
    if (!user) return res.redirect('/login'); 

    req.logIn(user, function(err) {
        if (err)  return next(err); 
        return res.redirect("/account/profile");
    });

})(req, res, next);
...
```

**Or** use it inside post method:

```
router.post("/register", function (req, res, next) {
    var newUser = new User({
        username: req.body.email
    });
    User.register(newUser, req.body.password, function (err, user) {
        if (err) {
            return res.render('account/signup');
        }

        // go to the next middleware
        next();

    });
}, passport.authenticate('local', { 
    successRedirect: '/account/profile',
    failureRedirect: '/login' 
}));
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your reply. When using the code inside post method i get the error ReferenceError: next is not defined

Comment: yes that's because you didn't pass next parameter to post method, it should be like this: `router.post("/register", function (req, res, next) {...`