# Bad Request Error after registering with passport.js

Tags: node.js, passport.js

Im using passport.js to register a user and then if the registration is successful, it redirects to a page which show "Hello and Welcome". But everytime I register a user i get redirected to a page with "bad request" written on it. But the user does get registered, It ends up id the database. I just can get it to redirect. Here is the code snippet:

```js
app.get("/page",function(req,res){
    if(req.isAuthenticated()){
        res.render("page");
    }else{
        res.redirect("/login");
    }
});


//register route

app.get("/register",function(req,res){
    res.render("register");
})

app.post("/register",function(req,res){
   User.register({username:req.body.userName},req.body.password,function(err,user){
       if(err){
           console.log(err);
           res.redirect("/register");
       }else{
           passport.authenticate("local")(req,res,function(){
               console.log(err);
               res.redirect("/page");
           })
       }
   })
})
```

Comment: are you using body-parser?

Comment: ans here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48096378/bad-request-when-registering-with-passport

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Bad Request when registering with passport](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48096378/bad-request-when-registering-with-passport)

Comment: I have tried other ways, used successRedirect and failureRedirect changed my post request method even used the next() keyword but the bloody thing doesn't work.